Blog page only shows one post
Hy  my dear friends i have a problem when I set my blog page which is in my website as my posts page then suddenly all my themes pics customization got removed and it shows only my post not all customization of theme

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
